# Divisão sempre resultando 0 mesmo com as variáveis tendo valores. Bug List/ArrayList

Tags: java

Estou treinando estatística então comecei a fazer um programinha para calcular o percentil. O problema/bug ocorre durante a divisão sempre retornando 0 mesmo com as variáveis tendo valores.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Float[] valores = new Float[] { 2f, 2f, 3f, 4f, 4f, 9f };
    System.out.println(percentilIgualAbaixo(valores, 3));
}

public static int percentilIgualAbaixo(Float[] array, float value) {
    List<Float> arr = Arrays.asList(array);
    int indexValue = arr.lastIndexOf(value) + 1;

    System.out.println("Index value:" + indexValue);
    System.out.println("tamanho list:" + arr.size());
    return indexValue / arr.size();
}
```

Saída:

```
Index value:3
tamanho list:6
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso não é *bug*, é um comportamento muito bem definido na [especificação da linguagem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17).

Basicamente, se ambos os operandos são `int`, o resultado da divisão também será `int`, e o valor é arredondado. Por isso ao dividir 3 por 6 o resultado é zero (pois o resultado da divisão, que é `0.5`, é arredondado para baixo, resultando no valor inteiro `0`).

Se quer que o resultado tenha as casas decimais, então o retorno do método não pode ser `int`. Você teria que mudar para `float` ou `double`, e ao fazer a conta, teria que fazer o *cast* para forçar os valores para um desses tipos. Algo assim:

```
// muda o retorno do método para float
public static float percentilIgualAbaixo(Float[] array, float value) {
    List<Float> arr = Arrays.asList(array);
    int indexValue = arr.lastIndexOf(value) + 1;
    System.out.println("Index value:" + indexValue);
    System.out.println("tamanho list:" + arr.size());

    // faz o cast dos valores para float
    return (float) indexValue / arr.size();
}
```

Assim, o resultado terá as casas decimais. No seu exemplo, com `3` e `6`, o resultado será `0.5`.

Repare também que você não precisa criar a list `temp`, pode pegar o retorno de `Arrays.asList` diretamente.

Comment: ah entendi obrigado.